# Hide 'New' Button on Recently View from Opportunity Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, button, recentlyviewed, salesfoce

Is it possible to hide the New (Standard Record creation button) from the Recently view of the Opportunity page?

[image]

Else is there any way we can customize the New button (Only Recently view not Other views) of the opportunity object.

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately that is not possible.

> The buttons on standard 'Recently Viewed' list views can not be
> customized.

[See details here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331581&language=en_US&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1)

Only way to remove the button would be to take away create access from opportunity for a profile.